# Separate the two arrays sent by json

Tags: javascript, json

I joined two arrays and sent it through json, like this:

```
$result = array_merge($json, $json1);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Now to receive the data I am doing this:

```
$.getJSON('./tarefasaad52', function (data) {
}
```

But I want to separate the arrays again.

**data returned:**

> 0: (3) ["T", 57, 22] 1: (3) ["T", 50, 23] 2: (3) ["M", 17, 22] 3: (3)
>   ["M", 50, 23] 4: (3) ["T", 42, 23]

Comment: Can you give a sample of the two arrays?

Comment: When you are the one who is sending it, just send the arrays without merging using two different keys, that way you reduce two unnecessary computations(Merging and seperating) on both server as well as client side.

Comment: if there's no other information stored or given about the initial arrays you cannot.

Comment: @bendataclear I put in the question the matrix example

Comment: @Dinesh Kumar But if you try to submit as you say, like this: `echo json_encode  ($json, $json1);` do not send data

Comment: I think you can't, because you don't know where to separate the arrays. You need additional parameter like length of the first array.

Comment: @BrunoPinto What I said is send the both arrays in a single JSON like {'arr1':[],'arr2':[]}. I guess it works this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associative Array can come to your rescue.

```
$result = array();
$result['json'] = array('A','B','C');
$result['json1'] = array('D','E','F');

echo json_encode($result);
```

The response part is easy, just parse the JSON and get the values using the index and name of the array you have passed.

```
$.getJSON('./tarefasaad52', function (data) {
    const json1 = data.json[0];
    const json2 = data.json1[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a fixed length or some other way to discern the cut off point you'll need to send the data differently:

You could create an array of the two arrays:

```
$result = array($json, $json1);
echo json_encode($result);
```

then in the client

```
$.getJSON('./tarefasaad52', function (data) {
    const json1 = data[0];
    const json2 = data[1];
}
```